# State 'pkg.upgrade' found in SLS 'apt-upgrade' is unavailable

Tags: salt-stack

I'm trying to build an SLS file that would perform `apt-get upgrade` call on an Ubuntu system. I am running in masterless mode.

Calling it directly from the command line works:

```
$ salt-call --local pkg.upgrade
[INFO    ] Executing command 'apt-get -q update' in directory '/root'
[INFO    ] Executing command "dpkg-query --showformat='${Status} ${Package} ${Version} ${Architecture}\n' -W" in directory '/root'
[INFO    ] Executing command ['apt-get', '-q', '-y', '-o', 'DPkg::Options::=--force-confold', '-o', 'DPkg::Options::=--force-confdef', 'dist-upgrade'] in directory '/root'
[INFO    ] Executing command "dpkg-query --showformat='${Status} ${Package} ${Version} ${Architecture}\n' -W" in directory '/root'
```

However the same call made from an SLS file (YAML format), doesn't work:

```
# top.sls
base:
  '*':
    - apt-upgrade


# apt-upgrade.sls
apt-upgrade:
  pkg:
    - upgrade


$ salt-call --local state.highstate
# ...
          ID: apt-upgrade
    Function: pkg.upgrade
      Result: False
     Comment: State 'pkg.upgrade' found in SLS 'apt-upgrade' is unavailable
     Started:
    Duration:
     Changes:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that you haven't understood the difference between [execution modules](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/index.html) and [state modules](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/).

pkg.upgrade exists in the [salt.modules.aptpkg](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.aptpkg.html) execution module. Thus you can call it from the `salt-call` command. To use it from a state file however, you'll have to use the [module.run](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.module.html) state.

Or better yet, you can see if you find something useful in [salt.states.pkg](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pkg.html) and use that instead.